About a function bounded by two polynomials
Let $P(x)=x^n+\Sigma_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^k $ and $Q(x)=x^n+\Sigma_{k=0}^{n-1}b_kx^k $ be polynomials with real coefficients such that  $n\ge 4$ is even and $a_{n-1}<b_{n-1} $ . Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $P(x)\le f(x) \le Q(x) \forall x\in \mathbb{R} $ .Then we conclude that
(a) $f(x)$ is a bounded function on $\mathbb{R} $
(b) $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R} $
(c) There exist $x_o \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $f(x_o)=0$
(d) $f(x)$ is continuous at least at one point $x_o \in\mathbb{R} $
My attempt :-  $f(x) \ge P(x)$ , and even degree polynomials with positive leading coefficient are unbounded so is $f(x)$
Given condition says $P(x)\neq Q(x)$ for at least one $c \in \mathbb{R} $
We define $$
f(x)= \begin{cases} P(x) & \text{if } x\in \mathbb{Q} , \\ Q(x) & \text{if } x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} . \end{cases}
$$
Assuming $ c\in \mathbb{Q} $ it can be shown $f(x) $ is not continous at $c$ by sequential criterion .So $f(x)$ is not continuous.
Now $Q(x)-P(x)=(b_{n-1}-a_{n-1})x^{n-1} + \Sigma_{k=0} ^{n-2} (b_k -a_k) x^k$
An odd degree polynomial with leading coefficient positive .
So $ \exists m\in \mathbb{R} $ s.t $Q(x)-P(x)\le 0 , \forall x<m $ But given $P(x)\le Q(x) \forall x $ , so we must have  $P(x)=f(x)=Q(x) \forall x <m$
So $f(x)$ is continuous at least at one point . I don't really know if I am proceeding right from above.
Kindly guide .Thanks in advance !

Actually $Q(x) - P(x) < 0$ for some $x$, which means that no such function $f$ exists. Is the question stated correctly?

@MartinR Yes sir , I am pretty sure about the correctness of the question

As the answer shows, an important option was left off your list: (e) $f$ does not exist.

As you already observed, $Q - P$ is a polynomial of odd degree with a positive leading coefficient. Then
$$
 \lim_{x \to -\infty} Q(x) - P(x) = - \infty
$$
and in particular, $Q(x) < P(x)$ for some $x \in \Bbb R$. This means that a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $P(x) \le f(x) \le Q(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ does not exist.
Therefore all statements about such functions $f$ are true – as vacuous thruths.
